# Separate users for migration and CRUD in one application EF + Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, database-migration

is it possible with `EntityFramework` and `Oracle` to use two schemas/connection strings: one for migration/database creation and second one to CRUD operations using synonyms to first schema?

Now when I setup context I'm passing connection string and I don't know how to use another connectionstring for CRUD. Crucial thing is two separate schemas.

Answer (score 0):

DbContext has constructor that accepts existing DBConnection:

```
public DbContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
```

You can create two System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection connections with different connection strings and pass them as DbConnection to DbContext.

Don't forget to either set contextOwnsConnection to true (this will dispose connection together with DbContext) or to dispose DbConnection manually after you done with DbContext.